# Is Update(GameTime) called before it's finished?

Tags: c#, xna, game-loop, latency

Code at the beginning of `Update(GameTime)` is being called over and over again, and code at the end of `Update(GameTime)` is only being called after a delay. Is `Update(GameTime)` called again before it's finished?

Relevant code:

```
    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Current Position (Outer): {Texture.Position.Y}");
        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
        {
            Jump(gameTime);
        }

        UpdateGravity(gameTime);

        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
        {
            velocity.X = -HorizontalMoveSpeed*(float) gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
        }
        else if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
        {
            velocity.X = HorizontalMoveSpeed*(float) gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
        }
        else
        {
            velocity.X = 0f;
        }

        Texture.Position += velocity;

        CheckCollisions();

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    private void UpdateGravity(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        velocity.Y += Gravity * (float) gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
    }

    private void Jump(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (jumping) return;
        jumping = true;
        velocity.Y -= JumpSpeed * (float) gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds;
    }

    private void CheckCollisions()
    {
        foreach (var platform in CryoGame.Platforms.Where(CollidesWith))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Current Position (Inner): {Texture.Position.Y}");
            var collision = false;

            var topInsideOther = Texture.Top <= platform.Texture.Bottom;
            var bottomOutsideOther = Texture.Bottom >= platform.Texture.Bottom;
            if (topInsideOther && bottomOutsideOther)
            {
                Texture.Top = platform.Texture.Bottom;
                collision = true;
            }

            var topOutsideOther = Texture.Top <= platform.Texture.Top;
            var bottomInsideOther = Texture.Bottom >= platform.Texture.Top;
            if (topOutsideOther && bottomInsideOther)
            {
                Texture.Bottom = platform.Texture.Top;
                collision = true;
            }

            if (collision)
            {
                velocity.Y = 0f;
            }
        }
    }
```

Example output:

```
Current Position (Outer): ...
Current Position (Outer): ...
Current Position (Outer): ...
Current Position (Outer): ...
Current Position (Outer): ...
Current Position (Outer): ...
Current Position (Outer): ...
Current Position (Outer): ...
Current Position (Outer): ...
Current Position (Outer): ...
Current Position (Outer): ...
Current Position (Inner): ...
```

```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You have a condition in `CheckCollision()` that only prints 'Inner' if the condition is true (the condition is that there has to be at least one `Platform` that is in the proper state to apply the code block to. So for several Update calls, the code flow went to `CheckCollision()` but there were no `Platform`s colliding (probably) so there was zero items to run the code in the `foreach` block so the block was skipped before running the print "Inner" line. At some point, something triggered a `CollidesWith` and the `foreach` had something to do so its code ran and "inner" was printed to the output console.